# PHP - automatically add records in an associative array using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, addition

I would like to automatically add records to the new associative array using a foreach loop. I have an array with the names of the following DOM elements:

```
$DOM = array('element2','element22','element222','element2222');
```

and a new associative array:

```
$NEW = array(
    'element1' => '',
    'element2' => '',
    'element3' => array(
        'element33' => array(
            'element333' => ''
        )
    )
);
```

Now using a foreach loop would add a new record/array to $NEW array:

```
foreach($DOM as $name){
    //Do something
}
```

expected result:

```
$NEW = array(
    'element1' => '',
    'element2' => array(
        'element22' => array(
            'element222' => array(
                'element2222' => ''
            )
        )
    ),
    'element3' => array(
        'element33' => array(
            'element333' => ''
        )
    )
);
```

You can do something like that? automate this process?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a rule where by you can't have an `element22` without having `element2`? **- or -** are you expecing if `element22` is present in `$DOM` that `element2` is also created?

Comment: I try to add value to multidimensional array. sometimes there is a parent and are added only children, and sometimes you have to create the entire path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `$DOM` contains keys to create nested array, with empty string value on deepest level. So you have to create such array:

```
$new_array = array();
$last = &$new_array;
foreach($DOM as $name){
    $last[$name] = array();
    $last = &$last[$name];
}
$last = '';
unset($last);
```

And merge it recursively with `$NEW`:

```
$NEW = array_merge_recursive($NEW, $new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify arrays in foreach-loops by passing them as references:

```
foreach($array as &$value)
    $value[] = $DOM
```

edit:

```
<?php

$DOM = array('element2','element22','element222','element2222');

$NEW = array(
    'element1' => '',
    'element2' => '',
    'element3' => array(
        'element33' => array(
            'element333' => ''
        )
    )
);

function insert(&$array, $ins) {
    $element = array_shift($ins);

    if($element == null) return;

    foreach($array as $k => &$v) {
        if($k === $element) {
            $v[current($ins)] = '';

            insert($v, $ins);
        }
    }
}

insert($NEW, $DOM);

var_dump($NEW);
```

Comment: if you can show how it would look in my case? I have first contact with the &$ in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array_push()` function

check this mabe help :

```
$DOM = array('element2','element22','element222','element2222');
$NEW = array('element1' => '', 'element2' => '', 'element3' => array('element33' => array('element333' => '')));
array_push($NEW, $DOM);

print_r($NEW);
```

see here :

[php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php‎](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

or here :

[www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp)